# JavaScript - Regex: URL has a param

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create an analog for php's `isset ($_GET[param])` but for JavaScript.
So long, I get this

```
[?&]param[&=]
```

But if param is at the end of URL (example.com?param) this regex won't work.
You can play with it here: https://regex101.com/r/fFeWPW/1

Comment: Replace `[&=]` with `(?:[&=]|$)` or `(?![^&=])`

Comment: This answer may help guide you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/1612146

Comment: Do you not just need to add on ? as in [?&]param[&=]? to make the [=&] optional? Then it matches http://example.com?param

Comment: Why don't you just parse the entire query string into an object, then you can just check if a particular key is in the object.

Comment: Why do people keep writing new parsers for standard data formats like URLs? And why do they insist on using regex for it? `console.log(new URL("http://example.com?param").searchParams.has("param"));`

Comment: @Quentin https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL Maybe, because it not compatible with all browsers?

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, don't you want to add your answer?  
George, thanks.  
mthomp, no, because example.com?paramz would match.  
Barmar, long way, I look for a shorter :)  
Quentin, it should work in old browsers.

Comment: Will this answer help too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make sure your match ends with `&`, `=` or end of string, you may replace the `[&=]` character class with a `(?:[&=]|$)` alternation group that will match `&`, `=` or end of string (note that `$` cannot be placed inside the character class as it would lose its special meaning there and will be treated as a `$` symbol), or you may use a negative lookahead `(?![^&=])` that fails the match if there is no `&` or `=` immediately after the current location, which might be a bit more efficient than an alternation group.

So, in your case, it will look like

```
[?&]param(?:[&=]|$)
```

or

```
[?&]param(?![^&=])
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HCj4uI/1)

JS demo:

```js
var strs = ['http://example.com?param', 'http://example.com?param=123', 'http://example.com?param&another','http://example.com?params'];
var rx = /[?&]param(?![^&=])/;
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s, "=>", rx.test(s))
}
```

Comment: Note that `[?&]param(?![^&=])` does not work inside a multiline test at regex101, but it works in real JS code when the strings are tested separately.